# Does IONIC support multi-threading and call jar lib developed in Java

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, cordova, ionic-framework

Currently, I'm working on project  using Ionic framework and Cordova.

We create some code witch running by java, it will be running on server.

but it will be the same main functionality on mobile devices using Ionic (java script + angularJS ...)

1- Can I get the jar file from the java project and recall those functions in Ionic using JavaAcript, I read many article: some people say it possible and some others say no !

2- About multi-threading, can Ionic support multi-threading or no ? because in my app I have some thread for asynchronisme consuming web services.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to access jar lib from cordova project you should use [ACE project](http://microsoft.github.io/ace/)
2. You can use [Webworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to achieve multi-threading in Javascript.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But it looks that ACE supported just by 2 platforms Android and iOS and not windows phoone and webapp ?

Comment: @Hani, If I am not wrong when you ask a way to access jar files, you are talking about Android platfrom?!

Comment: @Hani, And yes Ace project supports Android and iOs. Also as this project is backed by Microsoft they may focus on windows support in near future.

Comment: I create some code witch running by Java, it will be running on server (exp: conversion Excel files), and it will be the same functionality on mobile devices using Ionic so i would like to recall those functions in Ionic using JavaScript, i mean if i generate the jar file from the java project can i use those methode like java_project.conversion-function(filePath)..I use Ionic in order to get in the end Android, iOS, Windows Phone and webApp  applications